# How do I get my Pipeline Run Status in ADF using REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to check if my Pipeline A is running or not using REST API. I have written the following: However what do I pass and how do I get the status through this? I have gone through various documents but not able to get an output when I "trigger" it. I am extremely new to ADF as well

```
"name": "get pipeline A runs",
                "description": "pipeline A runs.",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/yy/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/zz/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "body": "()"
                }
            },
```

I have tried using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

basically i want to get if my pipeline is running or not and if it is not I have provided an IF ELSE condition.

Answer (score 2):

To check if my Pipeline A is running or not using REST API you can follow below steps:

Firstly, you need to get bearer token for Authentication with web activity.

> URL: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[telnetid]/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Btelnetid%5D/oauth2/token)

> METHOD: POST

> HEADERS: Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

> BODY: grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={id}&client_secret={secret}&resource=https://management.azure.com

Your appropriate values in above. or you can use any other authentication method.

**The web activity settings:**
[image]
**Values:**

> URL: [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01)

> METHOD: POST

> HEADERS: Authorization = Bearer token received from earlier web activity

> BODY: {"lastUpdatedAfter":"2023-07-12T00:00:00.33Z","lastUpdatedBefore":"2023-07-13T10:53:26Z","filters":[{"operand":"PipelineName","operator":"Equals","values":["pipeline1"]}]}
> (In boy fill values according to your requirement).

***OUTPUT:***
[image]

**My pipeline json:**

```json
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Web1",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{DataFactoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": "Bearer <token recieved from earlier web activity>"
                    },
                    "body": {
                        "lastUpdatedAfter": "2023-07-12T00:00:00.33Z",
                        "lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-07-13T10:53:26Z",
                        "filters": [
                            {
                                "operand": "PipelineName",
                                "operator": "Equals",
                                "values": [
                                    "pipeline1"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you manage to get the value of "last updated after" and "before" time values? @Pratik

Comment: last updated after and before value is given by you. refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP you can get pipelines star time and end time in monitor section  in ADF.

Comment: "last updated after" and "before" time is the approx. time where you want to get the status of pipeline runs. It should be in UTC format