# How to send mail if ADF Pipeline runs more then 10mins

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, oracle-adf

I need to send an email whenever my pipeline runs longer then 10mins. For sending mail I am using logic app but how to check if the time exceeds then 10mins? How can we check and do this in the pipeline itself? Can anyone kindly help me on this

Comment: you can send ADF logs to azure monitor (diagnostic settings) then you should be able to configure alert based on whatever metrics you d like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview

Comment: Use wait activity along with other activities in pipeline.

Comment: I cannot use alert and Wait activity will not work if the pipeline fails

Answer (score 0):

To send mail if ADF Pipeline runs more then 10min use Wait activity in parallel of your main pipeline and set the time to wait in seconds for 10 min(600 sec) in wait activity

[image]

After that with the [Rest Api get the status of pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs) through web activity.

```json
URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/@{pipeline().RunId}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

[image]

Then in the If activity the status of pipeline run is **In Progress** with expression `@equals(activity('Web1').output.value.status,'In progress')` then send the mail using web activity(logic app)

[image]

refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76670577) to more unerstanding on rest api with web activity

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below flow to achieve the ask :

1. at the end of the normal flow, have a set variable activity to assign a value to a variable w.r.t Pipeline status
2. In parallel , have an until activity to validate whether the execution time has exceeded the timeout value or the pipeline has completed and accordingly, take the necessary actions.

my blog explains it in detail :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2023/09/21/auto-cancel-long-running-pipelines-within-synapse-azure-data-factory/

Rather than pipeline cancellation, you can use logic app to trigger email